How to find $B_0(K)?$
Consider $K=\{(a),(b),(c),(ab),(bc),(ac)\}$ be  simplicial complex. find $B_0(K)$
My attempt : I know that  $B_1(K) =0 \implies H_1(K)=Z_1(K)$
$H_0(K)=C_0(K)/B_0(K)$  where $C_0(K)=\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$
How to find $B_0(K)?$
let $w \in B_0(K)$.Then there  exist  some $z \in C_1(K)$  such that $w=d_1(z)$ which implies  that  there  exist
$$z=l(ab)+m(bc)+n(ac)\implies  d_1(z)=d_1(l(ab)+m(bc)+n(ac))$$
$$w=l(b-a)+m(c-b)+n(c-a)=lb-la+mc-mb+nc-na$$
$$w=a(-l-n)+ b(l-m)+c(m+n)$$
After that, I am not able to continue.....

How do you define $B_n$?

@pyridoxal_trigeminus $B_0(K)$ =Im$(d_1)$

@pyridoxal_trigeminus $B_n(K)$ is the $n$ boundary group $C_n(K)$
